# Remove special characters and retain only one

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove all the special characters at the beginning. 
Next I want to remove all the special characters at ending of the string and retain only one character.

Exemple:

string:

```
!!on-line,,!!
```

result:

```
on-line,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
'!!on-line,,!!'.replace(/^\W+|(\W)\W*$/g, "$1");
"on-line,"
```

Comment: That doesn't leave the requested "only one [special] character" at the end of the string - per the OP's example, the result should be "on-line,"

Comment: Beat me to it, the second capture group `(\W*)` doesn't need to be captured.

Comment: See updated answer now, question wasn't formatter properly so couldn't understand the requirement properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
result = subject.replace(/^[^\w]+([0-9a-z- ]+\W)\W+$/img, "$1");
```

Input:

```
!!on-line,,!!
###nothing special!&&&&&
```

Output:

```
on-line,
nothing special!
```

One question is what you allow for non-special characters. At the moment, we are allowing letters, digits, dashes and spaces. This is specified by `[0-9a-z- ]` and can be tweaked by adding or replacing characters.